# pass interface to a class which implements this interface

Tags: java, class, interface, ignite, implements

Hi I am reading some code in a project which I just start to work on and see some code like this, which I could not understand.

```
public class A implements Ignite {
    protected Ignite ignite;
    .......
    protected void checkIgnite() {
        ......
    }

    @Override 
    public <K, V> IgniteCache<K, V> createCache(CacheConfiguration<K, V> cacheCfg) {
        checkIgnite(); 
        return ignite.createCache(cacheCfg);
    } 

}
```

I don't understand the meaning of this class.

First, this class A is to implements the interface Ignite.Then why pass the interface Ignite into this class?

Second, for the method createCache in class A, it return ignite.createCache(cacheCfg), then what exactly is the implementation of this method?

Thank you!

Comment: You read code in your projects and don't understand this? I though this is your project? then look for *wrapper classes* resp. *delegate pattern* which might add additional functionalities to existing ones.

Comment: I did not write this class. I am reading this class and try to understand what that mean.

Comment: Seems like decorator pattern. Something similar is done in Java's IO API. For example: Take a look at `java.io.BufferedReader`.

Comment: @anacron Oh thanks, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your `A` class is both a `Ignite` instance and holds an `Ignite` instance as a field.
It is a wrapper class conforming to a specific interface.

It provides a way to reuse a `Ignite` instance (that may be an instance of another class than `A`) while overriding some behaviors of it.

For example here :

```
@Override 
public <K, V> IgniteCache<K, V> createCache(CacheConfiguration<K, V> cacheCfg) {
    checkIgnite(); 
    return ignite.createCache(cacheCfg);
}
```

The `createCache()` implementation relies on the `createCache()` of the wrapped  `Ignite` instance but modifies its behavior by invoking before the  `checkIgnite()`method of the `A` class.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone tried to build a default method for an interface before Java 8.
When A has a constructor with an Ignite argument then you can do this:

```
IgniteCache<> cache = new A( someIgnite ).createCache( ... );
```

In Java 8, you would move createCache() directly as a default method to Ignite.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you ask about `IgniteSpringBean` class. This is wrapper for integration with Spring. This class encapsulate logic for properly creation and destroy Ignite instance. Also it check that bean was properly configured on calls of methods.